# smali: Handling Parameterised Classes

Tags: android, smali

Let's say I have an `List<E>`, I want to invoke its `add(E object)` method, and my list is actually a `List<String>`, how should i represent this invocation in smali?

Should it be

```
invoke-interface {v1, v2}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

or

```
invoke-interface {v1, v2}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the first.

```
invoke-interface {v1, v2}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

When in doubt, you can try what you want in java, compile it, dx it, then baksmali it :)